# How to step through foreach loop task?

Tags: debugging, ssis

In SSIS, how do I step through a foreach loop in debug to see each step within it individually? I've added breakpoints, but they don't seem to break on them in debug?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would add OnPreExecute breakpoint to the first task inside the foreach loop.